# how to get the last value of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

i want to say if the value of the last element in the `vector = 4 cout<<"Yes"` how can i write the code write  `if(v.size()==y)` where y is a number but it dosen't work i begin recently at writing codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n,x,y;
   cin >> n >> x >> y;
   vector<int> v(n);
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       cin >> v[i];
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if(v[0] == x)
       {cout<<"EASY";
           return 0;
       }
       if(v[0] == x && v.back() == y)
       {
           cout << "BOTH";
           return 0;
       }
       if(v.back()==y)
       {
           cout << "HARD";
           return 0;
       }
       if(v[0] != x && v.back() != y)
       {
           cout << "OKAY";
           return 0;
       }
    }}
```

Comment: The last element is accessible via `v.back();`. You first need to check the vector isn't empty.

Comment: `v.size()` returns the number of elements in the vector, not the last value.

Comment: could you please reformat your question so that it is actually clear what you are asking and what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: i want to say if(v.size()==y) cout<<"hard"; if the value of last element in the vector is 11 and y=11 cout hard

Comment: BTW, you last loop is useless.

Answer (score 26):

`v.size()` will returns the number of the elements in `v`, not the last element in the vector.

To get the last value of a `vector`, you can simply call [`std::vector::back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back).

Of course, you have to make sure the `vector` is not empty before that by checking [`std::vector::empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty).

```
if (!v.empty() && v.back()==y)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: i want to compare it with another value like if(v.size()==y) cout<<"hard"; where y is number like 4

Comment: @imagine Then just use `if(v.back() == y)`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao i use it but it didn't work could u run the code with this sample  3 1 2\n
             1 3 2

Comment: @imagine You can share your code so that I can point out the problem. Maybe update your question by adding them.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n,x,y;
   cin >> n >> x >> y;
   vector<int> v(n);
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       cin >> v[i];
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
       if(v[0] == x)
       {
           cout<<"EASY";
           return 0;
       }
       if(v[0] == x && v.size() == y)
       {
           cout << "BOTH";
           return 0;
       }
       if(v.size()==y)
       {cout << "HARD";
           return 0;}
       if(v[0] != x && v.size() != y)
       {cout << "OKAY";
  return 0;
       }}}

Comment: @herohuyongtao the code is above

Comment: @imagine don't put long code snippets in comments, please, especially when they're already in the original question. They're hard to read and harder to work with when they're dumped in comments. Plus the character limit means something might get cut off.

Comment: @imagine Please update your code in the question, not in the comment.

Comment: @herohuyongtao it is in the question

Comment: @imagine I mean your updated code after being modifined according to this answer.

Comment: @herohuyongtao how can i update the code it the firt time to use this site

Comment: @imagine Below your question, you will see the **`edit`** button.

Comment: @herohuyongtao i think i edit it

Comment: @imagine What's your expected output? Check out running result [here](http://ideone.com/QPEcab).

Comment: @herohuyongtao the out put should be both that is the problem   http://ahmed-aly.com/p.jsp?ID=6

Comment: @imagine Then correct your logic. And this become another question, ask it in SO. :P